# Изменить TObject внутри списка ComboBox

Tags: delphi

Имеется `ComboBox`. В нем хранится список объектов (класс, например, `TNewObject`), добавленных из базы данных через:

```
AddItem(Item: string; AObject: TObject)
```

Первый элемент в списке `[0]` должен быть переменным. Я пытался изменить его таким образом:

```
NewObject := TNewObject.Create;
NewObject.ID := 0;
NewObject.Name := '<строится отображаемое имя>';
NewObject.Value := <вычисляется значение>;
MyComboBox.Items[0] := NewObject;
```

Но, к сожалению, `Items[Index: Integer]` может принимать только `string` значения.

Каким образом я могу присвоить элементу `ComboBox` новое значение?

Потому, что метод, где надо полностью чистить и заново загружать список `Items`, мне не совсем подходит.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ComboBox1.Items` это `TStrings`, у которого дефолтное проперти - строки. Для доступа к проперти с объектами, нужно его явно указать, вот так:

```
ComboBox1.Items.Objects[0] := NewObject;
```

Comment: старый  объект не забыть куда-то деть еще.